# How supercookies works in Android?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, twitter, cookies

I would like to know if there is a cookie pool where several companies can query within Android so that it can store supercookie.
Or if it is site specific.
The foundation of this question was an event that occurred when I was talking about citizenship on Whatsup and, out of nowhere, suggestions for advertisements on Twitter about citizenship appeared.
I question how Twitter manages to capture the content of a conversation on Whatsup if they are not the same companies.
Note: I use twitter via the progressive web-app and not the app.

Comment: Ads are in 99% not loaded by code from the company that provides the app. Instead they use ad frameworks by Google, Facebook, ... SO it doesn't matter from which company an app is, more important is what ad frameworks the use.  For detecting ad frameworks and trackers in apps see https://exodus-privacy.eu.org/en/